# Multiple IPs to a single domain

Tags: apache, ubuntu, dns, ip-address, virtualhost

I am hosting multiple apps with the same domain and subdomains. Let's agree there are 3 apps with these server configs with a single domain of mywebsite.com

```
server1 ip is 123.234.345.23 ,and the app is located on app.mywebsite.com
server2 ip is 12.222.88.222 ,and the app is located on test.mywebsite.com
server1 ip is 123.123.123.23 ,and the app is located on mywebsite.com
```

I created a virutalhost config on the 3 servers like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin contacts@myemail.com
    ServerName mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mywebsite
    <Directory /var/www/html/mywebsite>
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mywebsite.com_error.log 
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mywebsite.com_access.log combined 
</VirtualHost>
```

I have configured the 3 IP addresses using A DNS of the domain.
server1 dns

```
Type: A, Name: @, Value: 123.234.345.23
Type: A, Name: *, Value: 123.234.345.23
```

server2 dns

```
Type: A, Name: @, Value: 12.222.88.222
Type: A, Name: *, Value: 12.222.88.222
```

server3 dns

```
Type: A, Name: @, Value: 123.123.123.23
Type: A, Name: *, Value: 123.123.123.23
```

When I try to access access server2 and server3, it always redirect me to server1. How do I fix this issue? Please, note I'm not doing load balancing, it just redirecting as appropriate.

Comment: share your All VirtualHost configuration.

Comment: @Pandurang  Thanks for the quick response. I forgot to add that one server uses NGINX while others are Apache. It's the NGINX server that the route is redirecting to.